# ImportError: cannot import name <model_class>

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am using `forms.ModelChoiceField` to have the choice loaded from a specific model entries:

```
from order.models import Region

class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    area = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all(),label=("Area"))
```

The problem I am facing is that when importing the class name from the app. I get the error:

> ImportError: cannot import name Region

Please not that `from order.models import Region` is working when testing it independently in the shell.

Any Idea what is causing so?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/home/salma/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/salma/Projects/Morabiz/Saludable/saludable_django/landing/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from order.models import Dish
  File "/home/salma/Projects/Morabiz/Saludable/saludable_django/order/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from order.forms import RegistrationFormNoUserName
  File "/home/salma/Projects/Morabiz/Saludable/saludable_django/order/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    from order.models import Region
ImportError: cannot import name Region
```

Comment: Please, post the traceback you get with your error

Comment: Probably a circular import. Does the model import the forms module?

Comment: just as a side not: you want to pass `Region.objects.all` (_no_ parens) to your `ModelChoiceField` - else you will have stale data.

Comment: @sk1p I added the traceback in the question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I do import a class from the forms to my model. I have "from order.forms import RegistrationFormNoUserName".

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers that's not actually true in the case of querysets, they are designed for this use case. It is true of lists based on queries though.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are right it was caused due to circular relation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you have a circular dependency between your forms and models files. You'll either need to refactor to remove the circularity, or if you really can't do that you'll have to move one of the imports into the function where it's used.

Comment: This helped someone out here