# Django: Cannot import name 'model'

Tags: python, django

So I am a student and I am trying to build a small shop using Django, so when I run the project on my laptop it works as expected but when I upload it to the server I got this error

> cannot import name 'CustomerOrderModel'

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from HomePage.models import Product
from HomePage.forms import Customer
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

#other functions

def customer_order_view(request, pk):
   product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=pk)
   form = Customer(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
      instance = form.save(commit=False)
      instance.customer_product_name = product
      instance.save()
      messages.success(request, "Success \n we will contact you soon")
      context = {'form': form, 'product': product}
   return render(request, 'HomePage/customerDetail.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from HomePage.models import CustomerOrderModel  #the error in this line 

class Customer(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:   
    model = CustomerOrderModel   
    fields = [# some fields]
```

**url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from HomePage.views import index_view, GiftView, FlowerView, BalloonView, 
detail_view, customer_order_view

app__name = 'HomePage'

urlpatterns = [
              url(r'^$', index_view, name='index'),
              url(r'^gift/$', GiftView.as_view(), name='gift'),
              url(r'^flower/$', FlowerView.as_view(), name='flower'),
              url(r'^balloon/$', BalloonView.as_view(), name='balloon'),
              url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', detail_view, name='detail'),
              url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/order/$', customer_order_view, 
                  name='product_form'),
                  ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from HomePage.models import Product, CustomerOrderModel

#some code
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

#some code
```

**this is picture of my file structure**

[image of the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdCRS.png)

**The Traceback**

```
  File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
 128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/django/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/views.py" in customer_order_view
49. def customer_order_view(request, pk):

File "/home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/forms.py" in <module>
4. class Customer(forms.ModelForm):

File "/home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/forms.py" in Customer
5.     class Meta:

File "/home/django/LovelyMemory/HomePage/forms.py" in Meta
6.         from HomePage.models import CustomerOrderModel

Exception Type: ImportError at /8/order/
Exception Value: cannot import name 'CustomerOrderModel'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: cannot import name <model\_class>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142366/importerror-cannot-import-name-model-class)

Comment: I looked at this question but I don't think it is the same because my project run on my laptop. @NinjaWarrior11

Comment: check models.py and forms.py in  same directory or not ??

Comment: Yes, they are under the same folder @RaviBhushan

Comment: is it models.py or model.py ??

Comment: if it is model.py then use
from .model import CustomerOrderModel

Comment: Python 2 or 3? You could try `from __future__ import absolute_import` if you're using relative imports. Also, on the server how are you running it? Are you providing the necessary python paths?

Comment: it is models.py @RaviBhushan

Comment: The website was working on the server, then I added some features and then when I pushed the update I got this error. And I am using python3 @markwalker_

Comment: You somehow did not name your file `models.py` but `model.py`?

Comment: I added picture of the project structure @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Error might not from this, so can you please post complete traceback ? That will be helpful

Comment: I added the traceback @SumeetKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see, this is due to circular import in your urls.py
You are doing
`from . import views`
You should do like 
`from .views import XyzView, AbcView`

This is because you are importing all imports done in views.py as well.
Hope you got the idea.

Comment: ok, I fixed every import that I have the way you said it. but I still can't import the model. the question has been updated it. I am really stuck in this problem for a long time. -_- @SumeetKumar

Comment: on what server you are hosting your website ?

Comment: I used this [turorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) to build the server, by the way, the code runs on my laptop with no problem @SumeetKumar

Comment: @waleed can you please share your urls.py, forms.py and views.py along with all the imports you are doing,

let me give you a hint, python is interpreted language, sequence of your import may also affect the output depending on python version.

Comment: if you are also using same form in your admin.py ? the you have to organize imorts in admin.py too

Comment: I have added all that you asked @SumeetKumar

Comment: i can see that very well, also i can see that at line number 6 in your forms.py you are importing same model again whic you have imported above as i guess from the code.

Comment: So What is the problem ? and what should I do to solve it? @SumeetKumar

Comment: You need to import that once

Comment: I am only importing it once, I tried inner import and global import and neither of them works @SumeetKumar

Comment: I am so desperate with this problem if you want me to push my project to Github and have better look at it @SumeetKumar

Comment: I run your code locally it is working as expected with python3.6, can you please confirm python version on server.

Comment: my laptop is 3.6 but the server is 3.5 @SumeetKumar

Comment: @waleed i have added some code to your repo via pull request, go through it and let me know if that works for you, coz that works for me very well on server as well.

Comment: Man, you are the best words don't explain the gratitude that I am in for you <3. just so I don't fall into this problem again what should I do in the future.

Comment: Thanks man, glad to help you. There is no such tricks to avoid circular import, just keep in mind to follow django conventions, organize your import in an order, also remember python is interpreted language, one hack to avoid circular import is local import just where you need that( bad practice though).

Comment: circular import was a trouble for me, too

Answer (score 2):

from model import CustomerOrderModel

Comment: I tried "from myproject.model import CustomerOrderModel" but it didn't work also

Comment: @waleed This answer should work. Can you please add your directory structure to your post.

Comment: I added a picture of the app structure @NinjaWarrior11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from HomePage.models import CustomerOrderModel
```

Comment: I tried it and got the same result, bear in mind that it doesn't work on the server only when I run it on a local server on my laptop it works fine.